# Are brackets in the WHERE clause standard sql

Tags: sql, standards

The course that I am currently doing uses brackets in its WHERE clauses like so:

```
SELECT bar
FROM   Foo
WHERE (CurrentState = 'happy');
```

Is this standard sql ?
If not then why use them?

Doesn't seem to be used in the Date & Darwen book I have.

---

**EDIT**

Just to clarify - I'm referring to 1992 sql standards

Comment: Yes, the SQL standard allows parentheses.

Comment: On the other hand, the quotes you put there aren't.

Comment: @Mat agreed - I've edited - that is the way single quotes look when typed in a doc file; I just copied from doc to SO. Weird

Comment: @someone who has voted to close - why isn't this a real question? "Are WHERE clause brackets standard (1992) sql?" ....what is not a real question about that!

Comment: @whytheq . . . The characters that you seem to be refering to are parentheses.  Brackets typically refers to "square brackets" which are `[` and `]` (as opposed to "curly brackets" which are `{` and `}`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff ....the brackets I'm referring to are in the code example of the OP - in the WHERE clause - I don't believe this is ambiguous?!

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... but for the record: the following characters are all "brackets" `()` / `[]` / `{}`. [**REFERENCE HERE**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/brackets)

Comment: @Whytheq . . . That looks like a good source.  Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ....upped your comment ....fair point! ....but I think worrying about which is specifically a _bracket_ and which is a _parenthesis_ isn't so important; or maybe there's a section in the 92 standards that explains how it uses the words?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  You can use parenthesis to bind components of where clauses.  This isn't necessary in your example, but if you had multiple `and` and `or` components, you might need parenthesis to either ensure correct order of operations or simply to self-document the query.

Example 1:

```
select *
from foo
where 
   (class='A' and subclass='B')
   or (class='C' and subclass='D')
```

In example 1, the parens aren't strictly required because `and` binds more tightly than `or`, but if you had multiple `or` conditions tied by `and` you would need it to get correct results, as in example 2 below.

Example 2:

```
select *
from foo
where 
   (class='A' or class='B')
   and (subclass='C' or subclass='D')
```

I use them in either case, because I don't like having to parse the sql in my head the same way the query optimizer does -- I'd rather be explicit about it and more quickly understand what the intent is.

Comment: +1 Thanks for info, although obviously I use brackets when things get complicated with boolean logic just wondered why my course material was using them when there are no `AND` or `OR` operators.

Comment: Course material is odd that way sometimes.  Often, they do silly things just to get you in a habit the professor thinks is useful.  You might ask your prof why s/he thinks it's important in that case.

Answer (score 5):

They are optional. They make sense for more complex WHERE statements.

```
... WHERE (created > '2012-10' AND created < '2013-01') 
OR (modified > '2012-10' AND modified < '2013-01')
```

Answer (score 4):

No. They are only required to be used when you have `AND` on `OR` conditions in your statement to avoid shortcircuits, just like this:

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE  col1 > 1 AND col2 < 3 AND col3 >= OR col3 = 1 AND col5 < 1
```

The above query will give you unexpected result as it will not determine the correct condition it will take. A round brackets will help you segregate condition in this case,

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE  col1 > 1 AND col2 < 3 AND (col3 >= OR col3 = 1) AND col5 < 1
```

by the way, it should be single quotes `' '` not `‘ ’`

Comment: What do you mean by "No."? The question is "Are brackets in the WHERE clause standard sql"

Comment: @Mat are they standard sql?

Comment: They might be valid but they are not standard.

Comment: @JW웃: how can they be "required to be used" if they're not standard? (I've never read a SQL standard.)

Comment: @Mat "only required"..now you tell me if they are standard.

Comment: You saying that the answer to "are parens in the SQL standard" is no is incorrect. Parenthesized expressions are definitely in the SQL standard. They might not be required in the example posted, but they are standard.

Comment: @JW웃 I've changed the quotes - that was related to typing single quotes into WORD and then from there to SO.

Comment: @whytheq: parens are in the SQL 2008 draft I just looked up. I seriously doubt they could be absent from any prior version.

Comment: @Mat seems like it is the standard that they are optional !