# MySQL where and clauses in brackets

Tags: mysql

I have a question about MySQL where and clauses. Are the two following statements the same:

```
1. select * from products where id <> 1 and num > 2

2. select * from products where (id <> 1 and num > 2)
```

Comment: both are same as `and` clause will check all conditions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are brackets in the WHERE clause standard sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122695/are-brackets-in-the-where-clause-standard-sql)

Comment: Both statements are Same and brackets are optional in this case. They make sense for more complex WHERE statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. The brackets here play the same role as all brackets do in conditionals.

When used with `AND` then they don't have any impact on the condition, as long as it only has `AND` within it. Same applies to statements that only has `OR` within. When used with both `AND` and `OR` then they do have an impact as long as they are used on sub-operations and not on the condition as a whole:

```
A AND (B OR C) != (A AND B) OR C
```

In SQL, brackets are also used for `IN` clause, `EXISTS`, sub-queries and other fundamentals