# Parentheses Placement in Where Statements

Tags: sql-server

I've read over some resources and like posts on this website [Are brackets in the WHERE clause standard sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122695/are-brackets-in-the-where-clause-standard-sql). However, I'm still having trouble getting all of the **where filters** to work.

When running the following code, my results still return records that contain values other than the ones I'm attempting to filter out.

I'm trying to return all values who have an (1) `PT_ACUITY` that equals `3 - Two+ Resources` and who also have a  (2) `Track_Group equaling 'ED Tracking Group'`and (3) whose `CHECKIN_DATE_TIME` falls within the state and end date variables and (4) who also do not have a `REASON_FOR_VISIT` that contains any of the wildcard terms.

I would like the returning records to meet all four arguments. Thanks!

```
use EMTCQIData

DECLARE @StartDate Date
DECLARE @EndDate Date

Set @StartDate = '01/01/2017'
Set @EndDate = '12/21/2018'

Select pt_fin, TRACKING_GROUP, PT_MRN, RESULT_DT_TM, NOTE_TYPE, 
RESULT_TITLE_TEXT, AUTHOR, ACTION_PRSNL, Result

from ED_NOTES_MASTER    

WHERE   (TRACK_GROUP    =   'ED Tracking Group')
AND     (PT_ACUITY      =   '3 - Two+ Resources')
AND     (CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate)
AND     (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%asthma%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicide%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicidal%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicide%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicidal%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%FD-12%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%behavioral%')
OR      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%overdose%')
Or      (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%aggression%')
```

Comment: Please provide your whole select query, then we'll be able to assist better

Comment: changing the OR to AND should fix it, no?

Comment: Thanks @Birel, please see corrected query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wanted a variable @x to be not equal to 1 or 2, then you could write

@X <> 1 AND @X <> 2

but if you wrote

@X <> 1 OR @X <> 2

then it will be true for any number, so if @X was 1, then the second half is true, making the whole thing true

```
WHERE TRACK_GROUP = 'ED Tracking Group' AND  PT_ACUITY='3 - Two+ Resources' AND CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate 
    AND 
        (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%asthma%'   --it needs to be NOT like any of these, so all the conditions have to be true
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%')   --that is to say, each of the conditions is NOT like the value in quotes
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicide%' 
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicidal%'
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicide%'
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicidal%'
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%FD-12%'
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%behavioral%'
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%overdose%'
     AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%aggression%' )
```

Answer (score 5):

First off, formatting your query will make it more readable and easier for you to visualize and dissect.

If I understand your question.

```
WHERE  TRACK_GROUP = 'ED Tracking Group'
  AND  PT_ACUITY='3 - Two+ Resources'
  AND  CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate 
  AND  CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate
  AND  (    REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%asthma%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicide%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicidal%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicide%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicidal%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%FD-12%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%behavioral%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%overdose%' 
        AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%aggression%' 
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

Well just based on your WHERE clause you probably don't need any parenthesis, but I grouped them together like this:

```
WHERE 
(TRACK_GROUP = 'ED Tracking Group' AND  PT_ACUITY='3 - Two+ Resources' 
AND CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate)
 AND (REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%asthma%'
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%psych%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicide%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%suicidal%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicide%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%homicidal%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%FD-12%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%behavioral%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%overdose%' 
 AND REASON_FOR_VISIT Not Like '%aggression%')
```

Your problem was having all those ORs in there