# Update a column value if two specific conditions are met in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm very much a newbie to programming.
I am trying to update my table column labelled 'bonus' with a new value of 505.99 if two conditions are met: if the givenname is Mary and their bonus is currently 155.99, or if their occupation is a Model and their bonus is also currently 155.99. 7 rows should be updated but only 1 is being updated.
The query looks like it should work to me so wondering what I am missing?
Looking for any pointers!
Thanks in advance

```
UPDATE customers
SET bonus = 505.99
WHERE occupation = 'Model' AND bonus = 155.99
OR givenname = 'Mary' AND bonus = 155.99;
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)?

Comment: Which one is updated? do you have an issue with case sensitivity? please publish sample date and table definition as text or to fiddle - I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/3gNMSgWR

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use parentheses like these?

```sql
UPDATE customers
SET bonus = 505.99
WHERE
    (occupation = 'Model' AND bonus = 155.99)
    OR
    (givenname = 'Mary' AND bonus = 155.99);
```

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: @forpas Here are some good examples and explanations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122695/are-brackets-in-the-where-clause-standard-sql

Besides making it more readable they also can affect the evaluation order, similar to normal math. 5 + 5 * 2 = 5 + 10 = 15 is different than (5 + 5) * 2 = 10 * 2 = 20.

Comment: No, the parentheses do not affect the evaluation order because `a and b or c and d` is evaluated as `(a and b) or (c and d)`.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the order of evaluation in this case. Nevertheless it adds more readability and clarity IMHO.

Comment: Does it solve any problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AND` and `OR` conditions properly when you use those simultaneously.

Let us build your query :

As we know we are going to set value wherever following holds true.

1. Either `occupation = 'Model' OR givenname = 'Mary'`
   **This should be written with `OR`** together
2. `bonus = 155.99` : This we can add separately using `AND` in the select query.

So; the correct condition to use is `(occupation = 'Model' OR givenname = 'Mary') and bonus = 155.99;`

We can re-write the above query as :

```
UPDATE customers
SET bonus = 505.99
WHERE bonus = 155.99
AND (occupation = 'Model' OR givenname = 'Mary');
```

You can find more good [examples here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/and_or.php#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20AND%20condition%20and,order%20to%20evaluate%20each%20condition.) :

Comment: How is this different?

Comment: Hi @forpas:
`I am applying the rule similar to BODMAS for where condition.`
You can find similar examples here :
https://codepedia.info/sql-using-parentheses-with-and-or-condition-is-necessary-with-where-clause-to-gives-expected-result

Comment: Does the rule that you apply make any difference to the evaluation of the condition in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Let me explain you this with sqlfiddle.

I am creating one.
Please give me 10 minutes

Comment: I am new to sqlfiddle. Please give me little more time; I shall insert sample data similar to OP and show it